# the file received as empty while sending using TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

im trying to send file over TCP using C#
while receiving file 
i found that it's  0 KB
how to Fix it ?
here's the Code
//server

```
 TcpListener list = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            list.Start();
            TcpClient client  = list.AcceptTcpClient();//accepting connection with client when send button is clicked there .. !
            StreamReader s = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            Stream st = client.GetStream();
            rd = s.ReadLine();
            //FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(textBox1.Text + "\\" + rd.Substring(0, rd.LastIndexOf('.')), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);//new file stream

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);//new file stream

            int byteSize = 0;
            byte[] b1 = new byte[2048];



            while ((byteSize = st.Read(b1, 0, b1.Length)) > 0)//if stream read any thing that mean the file didn't finish yet !
            {
              fileStream.Write(b1, 0, byteSize);//write data in file till it finishes


            }
```

Comment: Can you be very explicit about what *does* happen? i.e. what you are sending, and what you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your file has been consumed in the `StreamReader`'s buffer, but you are reading from the `Stream`. Frankly, it isn't a good idea to use both. You may want to discard the `StreamReader` completely and just use the `Stream` - it just means you'll need to look for the end of the text line yourself, by reading until you see a byte with decimal value `10` or `13`.